# Как совместить ReplyKeyboardRemove() и InlineKerboardMarkup в одном сообщении aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Пишу телеграм бота на aiogram. Возник вопрос, как можно совместить ReplyKeyboardRemove() и InlineKerboardMarkup в одном сообщении? Т.е. чтобы при отправке ботом этого сообщения удалялась обычная клавиатура, а к сообщению добавлялась inline клавиатура.

**UPD**(1001001):

Мне это нужно для того, чтобы у пользователя не возникало желания нажать на кнопку ещё раз. Я обрабатываю такие случаи, но всё же это нежелательно.
Можно конечно ограничиться скрытием клавиатуры, т.е. установив `one_time_keyboard=True`, но лучше удалить клавиатуру полностью.

Comment: зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Ну такой функционал может понадобиться.

Comment: Для чего он может понадобиться? Попробуйте дополнить ваш ответ, в данном виде он не понятен.

Comment: Обновил. Теперь стало понятнее?)

Comment: А вам обязательно использовать replykeybard? Если вам требуется что-то похожее на меню то можно использовать [editMessageText](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/edit_message_text.html) в котором вы можете изменять inlinekeyboard. Чем избавите себя от проблемы дабл клика. Насколько мне известно обычная клава, никуда не испаряется, а просто скрывается.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!